# python multiprocessing manager.dict() is blocking

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I would like to have main python process to create a child process that continuosly updates an object (Node). An object needs to be accessible from both main process and child process. Once I add instance of my Node object to instance of manager.dict() when trying to retrieve Node object from it, main process is blocked.
Below is a simplified code

**test.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host
        self.refreshed = 0

    def refresh(self):
        self.refreshed = int(time.time())

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node host:%s' % (self.host,)

man = Manager()
d = man.dict()


def worker(d):
    while True:
        node = d['n1']
        node.refresh()
        d['n1'] = node
        time.sleep(3)

proc = Process(target=worker, args=(d,))
```

**run.py**

```
import test

test.d['n1'] = test.Node('localhost')
test.proc.start()
```

If I drop to interpreter here and do `test.d.items()` it will block.

**Update**
If I alter the code and instead of Node instance just use primitive value, e.g. increment an int, it works fine.

**Update**
If I move code from `run.py` to the bottom of `test.py` so everything is in the same scope, then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

try to put your code behind

`if __name__ == "main":`

for example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    man = Manager()
    d = man.dict()
    proc = Process(target=worker, args=(d,))
```